# GASのウェブアプリケーションをjsのfetchで実行する方法

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

#### 前提

GASを使用
ウェブアプリケーションのデプロイ設定を下記で行いました。

**・次のユーザーとして実行**
**ウェブアプリケーションにアクセスしているユーザ**

**・アクセスできるユーザ**
**組織 内の全員**

#### 実現したいこと

htmlファイルに記載したjavascriptから、デプロイを行なったGASの結果を取得したです。

また、実行・アクセスできるユーザは組織内のユーザのみに限定したいので、
GASデプロイ設定の「次のユーザーとして実行」と「アクセスできるユーザ」は上記の設定でお願いしたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

上記の設定にすると処理結果を受け取れてません。

chromeのコンソールで確認するとこのような中身になってました。

```
Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
[[Prototype]]: Response

戻り値:
```

#### 該当のソースコード

GASのコード

```
function doGet(e) {

  let json = {
    'text': 'aaaa'
  }
  let res = JSON.stringify(json)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(res).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
}
```

HTMLのコード

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        let url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/****/exec';

        let option = {
            'mode': 'no-cors'
            , 'method': 'GET'
            , 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        };

        let text = '';
        fetch(url, option)
        .then(
            function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                return res.text();
            }
        ).then(
            function(json) {
                text = json;
                console.log("戻り値:" + json);
            }
        ).catch(function(exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

#### 試したこと

GASのデプロイ設定を下記のようにすると問題ないことは確認できました。

**・次のユーザーとして実行**
**自分**

**・アクセスできるユーザ**
**全員**

HTMLに記載のoption変数を下記に変更

```js
        let option = {
            'method': 'GET'
            , 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        };
```

chromeのコンソール

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?u…mZixddpbUVg&lib=Mv9wYkUhvGHhGDLT7HCgnKd1sAI6oo1Au', redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: true
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=t6AwjjspV1kU-_1qlO63Z70XrFMres0fI6ZSpURhXch6TbNOgrYKmA3bFlVl5B6MYfaE8wqe2DRC_OgKWl0SejQeQtPVB4Pgm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnPBIAyb9Xw1qqs9Rjqalb0gct2gCt1kEk1G9y721k1e5r_xTxoPnJWNKJQ7J6HlSX7MjKYTMKDczKxY3e265L2RmZixddpbUVg&lib=Mv9wYkUhvGHhGDLT7HCgnKd1sAI6oo1Au"
[[Prototype]]: Response
戻り値:{"text":"aaaa"}
```

しかし、この設定だと
**Urlを知っていると誰でも実行可能で危険**
なのでこの設定は避けたいです。

fetchのinit引数にcredentials と下記の3つを一つずつ試しましたが結果は変わらずでした。

```
'include'
'same-origin'
'omit'
```

---

ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() で値を取得し
HTMLファイルに反映させましたが、結果は変わらずでした。

ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()の値を取得し、設定した方法

1. ダミー関数をGASのエディタから実行して、コンソールに表示された値をコピー
2. 1 でコピーした値をHTMLファイルの oAuthToken の値にセット

```
// ダミー関数
function myFunction() {
  console.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
}
```

GASでのスコープ設定

```js
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts"
  ]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        let url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec';

        let oAuthToken = 'ya29.A0ARrdaM-b4Qkdt970ib90xUfoXIsCqkJYZWyg1KnJw04kIBlFvSZ1QwaP-u_ed5BbIamgpT6p-MWqYPoY5RtMWvXXt06DqmeIE6C2cromOec2WSlY4wQanAvAhLpoGAoZKf80377UACfIuoAGLqV8ks8X-MVpnKn5DO7icpB6KxSfhDI';

        let option = {
            'mode': 'no-cors'
            , 'method': 'GET'
            , 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            , 'headers': {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + oAuthToken
            }
        };

        let text = '';
        fetch(url, option)
        .then(
            function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                return res.text();
            }
        ).then(
            function(json) {
                text = json;
                console.log("戻り値:" + json);
            }
        ).catch(function(exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

`'mode': 'no-cors'`　を外して実行

GASは変更なし

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        let url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx3DG-O0pFRLzpTxqM7cgkF8bMvNvsCYU97upqK9P7G-T2NuAzHyQ5iaPuHY_1SnMNm/exec';

        let oAuthToken = 'ya29.A0ARrdaM_zEoVPRmZHqKDUC06EdbXc7PzhJEW1IjYknNyjSpQI0_mfHbEVwQaSFeYJuIccwmBKJn7mCZ9JCINlswjtLIRxM-7mSMey-tGAVYG78Z4MSmLihutuyrqFZxgvcPKmesrSvRqIYSgMTLUY6lFZJX855PaBSOZD8pSlgL4Z4uYD';

        let option = {
            // 'mode': 'no-cors'
            /*,*/ 'method': 'GET'
            , 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            , 'headers': {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + oAuthToken
            }
        };

        let text = '';
        fetch(url, option)
        .then(
            function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                return res.text();
            }
        ).then(
            function(json) {
                text = json;
                console.log("戻り値:" + json);
            }
        ).catch(function(exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

curlでの実行

```sh
$ curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx3DG-O0pFRLzpTxqM7cgkF8bMvNvsCYU97upqK9P7G-T2NuAzHyQ5iaPuHY_1SnMNm/exec" -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.A0ARrdaM_zEoVPRmZHqKDUC06EdbXc7PzhJEW1IjYknNyjSpQI0_mfHbEVwQaSFeYJuIccwmBKJn7mCZ9JCINlswjtLIRxM-7mSMey-tGAVYG78Z4MSmLihutuyrqFZxgvcPKmesrSvRqIYSgMTLUY6lFZJX855PaBSOZD8pSlgL4Z4uYD"
{"text":"aaaa"}
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/gokr4b71kgkjku) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: > 他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿　　こちら側ではあまり知見を持った方がいないのではないかと思い、このサイトにも投稿を行いました。問題があるようでしたら、質問を削除いたしますので、ご連絡ください。

Comment: Web Appsの設定を`次のユーザーとして実行: ウェブアプリケーションにアクセスしているユーザ`、且つ、`アクセスできるユーザ: 組織 内の全員`として、Web Appsをスクリプトから実行する場合は、次の２つの手順が必要です。1. Web Appsのスクリプトを実行させたいユーザと共有する。2. リクエストの際にリクエストヘッダへアクセストークン含めて実行する。表示されている`組織 内の全員`の設定から、もしもWeb Appsのスクリプトを作成したGoogle Apps Script projectが既に組織内のユーザと共有されている場合は改めて共有する必要はありません。アクセストークンのみ使用してください。その際は、`option`を`let option = {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ###your access token###"}}`に変更してください。ご使用されている実際の環境の詳細については不明なため、これでエラーが発生するようですと、管理者に問い合わせるのもありと思いました。確実な回答かどうか不明なためコメントにしました。

Comment: @Tanaike 
> 1. Web Appsのスクリプトを実行させたいユーザと共有する。
こちらに関しては、動作確認のために自分のアカウントでGASを作成したので、問題ないと考えてます。

> 2. リクエストの際にリクエストヘッダへアクセストークン含めて実行する。
アクセストークンの取得は
GASのコードにて　`ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` 　で問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。1に関して、自身がオーナーであるGAS projectを自身のアカウントでアクセスする場合は、そのままで問題ないと思われます。2に関して、テストで使用するためのアクセストークンを取得するだけなら`ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`で取得したアクセストークンをそのまま使用できます。ただし、この場合、Drive API用のscopeを含めるようにしてください。これがポイントのようです。[Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#access-token-for-accessing-to-web-apps)

Comment: @Tanaike ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() で取得した値を
HTMLコード側に反映しましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

本質問の試したことに実施結果を追記してますので、ご確認ください

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。大変なご迷惑をお掛けしまして申し訳ありません。追加していただいたスクリプトを見ますと、`'mode': 'no-cors'`が含まれているようです。これを削除して再度テストしてみてください。また、今の場合、もしもこの修正でもfetchからのアクセスができないようであれば、テストとして、curlコマンドを使って試してみてください。curlコマンドで動作が確認できるようであれば、Web Apps側、アクセストークンの使用については問題ないと判断することができるかと思われます。

Comment: @Tanaike  > 'mode': 'no-cors' を外して実行すると、corsエラーとなり実行できない状態になります。　`Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec' from origin 'https://****' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`　GASのスクリプト実行もエラーになりました。　`GET https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec net::ERR_FAILED
（匿名） @ tow_gas_index.html:24`

Comment: なお、curlでの実行は正常に終了しました。両方とも実施したことに追記していますのでご確認ください。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。curlコマンドで動作したとのことから、Web Appsの設定自体は問題ないと思われます。fetchを使った場合のエラーですが、Preflight requestが原因の可能性ではないかと心配しています。以前は表示されているスクリプトで問題なかったのですが、最近はこのようなエラーが出てしまうようです。この場合、ブラウザ依存の可能性もありますので、今テストで使用しているのとは別のブラウザで試すのはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @Tanaike > Preflight requestが原因の可能性
Safariで実行すると、この文言が表示されているのを確認しました。
> ブラウザ依存の可能性もありますので、今テストで使用しているのとは別のブラウザで試すのはいかがでしょうか。
実施の際は Google Chromeを使用してました。このGASを動作する際はGoogle Chromeである必要があります。


また、gasの使用方法に関してですが
弊社のコーポレートサイトにて、GASのdoGetもしくはdoPost実行ボタンを配置。
実行ボタンをクリックすると、デプロイしたGASの処理が動き、処理結果を返すようにする必要があります。

このGAS呼び出しも、ページ遷移を行う方法ではなく、fetchを使用しての非同期呼び出しで実現する必要があります。
処理を行う部分の作成はできているのですが、外部のhtmlコードから実行することができずなので、質問を行なっています。

こういったことが可能なのか不明ですが、
外部のhtmlコードから実行ボタン押下時に、ポップアップなどで、ユーザアカウントのログインも実施する必要があります。
こちらは、GASのデプロイ設定で、対応できるのでは無いかとみてますが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。今のところ、上記のWebAppsの設定下でブラウザからHTTP requestでWeb Appsへアクセスする際に問題が発生するようです。例えば、WebAppsの設定をアクセストークンを使わない設定にできるならシンプルに解決できます。これができないようであれば、回避策としてはHTMLをGASプロジェクト内に配置することでブラウザから直接Web Appsへアクセスできますので、この問題は回避できるのではないかと思われます。ただ、提示された質問や返信からはこれらが可能かどうかは判断できません。

Comment: @Tanaike 
> 例えば、WebAppsの設定をアクセストークンを使わない設定にできるならシンプルに解決できます。
こちらの方法は、デプロイ設定を変更するということでしょうか？
次のユーザーとして実行を自分、アクセスできるユーザを全員にすれば実行できますが、URLを知っていると誰でも実行できてしまうので
セキュリティ的にアウトだと考えてます。

> 回避策としてはHTMLをGASプロジェクト内に配置することでブラウザから直接Web Appsへアクセスできますので、この問題は回避できるのではないかと思われます。
こちらに関しては、外部のhtml で<iframe src="webデプロイURL" >　の定義を行なって、GAS内のhtmlを表示するイメージでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。 1. `セキュリティ的にアウト`について、そちらの期待する状況については不明ですが、例えばシンプルなセキュリティとしてはAPI keyのような方法もありますが、これは期待する状況とは異なりますか？ 2. `こちらに関しては、外部のhtml で<iframe src="webデプロイURL" >　の定義を行なって、GAS内のhtmlを表示するイメージでしょうか？`について、`ContentService.createTextOutput`を返す現状の場合は403のエラーが発生すると思われます。この場合、XFrameを許可して`HtmlService.createHtmlOutput`を返すことで自身のアカウントではアクセスできますが、他のアカウントではXFrameのエラーが発生すると思われます。そのため、WebAppsのURLを直接開くのが良さそうに思いますが、これはそちらの期待する状況とは異なりますか？これらが役に立たない場合は謝罪致します。

Comment: @Tanaike 
すみません。言葉足らずになっていました。
試したことのこの部分に当たりますが、
> GASのデプロイ設定を下記のようにすると問題ないことは確認できました。
>・次のユーザーとして実行　自分
>・アクセスできるユーザ　全員
GASのデプロイ設定で、誰もがアクセス可能の状態になると
悪意を持った第三者が、たまたま入力したURLが、GASのウェブアプリURL(https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec) だった場合
実行結果が返ってくることを知ってしまいます。

こうなった場合、悪意を持った第三者に何をされるかわからないので、この設定にはせず

次のユーザーとして実行：ウェブアプリケーションにアクセスしているユーザ
アクセスできるユーザ：組織 内の全員
この設定にして、API化させたいのです。
この設定ならば、アクセスできるユーザが弊社の社員のみになるので、悪意を持った第三者がアクセスしても弾くことができ、安全に使用できると考えています。

Comment: > シンプルなセキュリティとしてはAPI keyのような方法もありますが
どのようなイメージで実装するのか不明ですが、外部のhtmlにAPI keyを記載するのでしょうか？
これだと、外部のhtml（弊社のコーポレートサイト）は誰でもアクセスできるので、結局誰でも実行可能になってしまうのでは無いでしょうか？
それとも、別の方法でGoogleアカウント認証を行い、認証成功時にAPIkeyを取得し、使用するといった感じでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。`これだと、外部のhtml（弊社のコーポレートサイト）は誰でもアクセスできるので、結局誰でも実行可能になってしまうのでは無いでしょうか？ それとも、別の方法でGoogleアカウント認証を行い、認証成功時にAPIkeyを取得し、使用するといった感じでしょうか？`について、Google APIで使用するAPIキーのような使い方を想定しました。ただ、これについても直接的な解決策がないことから回避策の一つです。また、ご返事から、２つ目の回避策は使用しないとの理解で宜しいでしょうか。現状直接の解決策が見当たらないため、回避策を提案してしまったことを深く謝罪致します。

Comment: @Tanaike 
> また、ご返事から、２つ目の回避策は使用しないとの理解で宜しいでしょうか
はい。どのようにAPIキーを設定し、取得し、GASのウェブアプリを実行すればよいかわからないので、何も着手はしていない状態になります。

やはり、GASのウェブアプリを使用して、外部のhtmlに記載した fetchの処理実行時に、Googleアカウント認証を行いつつ、GASのウェブアプリを実行することはできない仕様なのでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。`はい。どのようにAPIキーを設定し、取得し、GASのウェブアプリを実行すればよいかわからないので、何も着手はしていない状態になります。`について、了解しました。`やはり、GASのウェブアプリを使用して、外部のhtmlに記載した fetchの処理実行時に、Googleアカウント認証を行いつつ、GASのウェブアプリを実行することはできない仕様なのでしょうか？`について、現状上記のWebAppsの設定ではPreflight requestが原因でこれに対する直接の解決策が見当たらないため、シンプルと思われる回避策を提案させていただきましたが、これについて再度深く謝罪致します。

Comment: @Tanaike
> 現状上記のWebAppsの設定ではPreflight requestが原因でこれに対する直接の解決策が見当たらないため、シンプルと思われる回避策を提案させていただきました

あくまでこうすれば、実行できるの案であって、実装方法については、ご存じない認識で問題無いでしょうか？

また、このように実装方法が不明な場合は、Googleの公式にお問合せを行った方が良いでしょうか？

Comment: @Tanaike > 実装方法

こちらのコメントにあった（https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88083/gas%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a6%e3%82%a7%e3%83%96%e3%82%a2%e3%83%97%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b1%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%92js%e3%81%aefetch%e3%81%a7%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95?noredirect=1#comment99959_88083）
> Google APIで使用するAPIキーのような使い方を想定しました。

この、Google APIで使用するAPIキーの取得と、取得したAPIキーを使用してGASのウェブアプリURLを呼び出す方法になります。
調べ方が悪いのか、Google APIのAPIキー取得方法を記載した方法が見つからず。
また、GASのウェブアプリURLをGoogle APIキーを使用して呼び出す方法も見つからずで
どうしようもない状態です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

- Google OAuth 2.0 認証を使用したログイン
- GCPのOAuth同意画面、認証情報のAPIキーとOAuth 2.0 クライアント IDの作成
- GAS側で実行可能APIを使用
  上記をすることでjsのfetchから実行できることを確認しました。

実装したコードは以下になります。

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="auth-div" style="display: none;">
        <span>アカウント認証していないので、認証ボタンを表示する</span>
        <button id="auth-btn" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">認証</button>
    </div>
    <div id="exec-div" style="display: none;">
        <span>アカウント認証が問題無いので、実行ボタンを表示する</span>
        <button id="exec-btn" onclick="execution(event)">実行</button>
        <div>
            実行結果: <label id="exec-result"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
var CLIENT_ID = 'GCPの認証情報 Auth 2.0のクライアントID';

var API_KEY = 'GCPの認証情報 APIキー';

var SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request'
];

var SCRIPT_ID = 'GASの実行可能APIにある、/exec前のID';

var DISCOVERY_DOCS = [
    "https://script.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"
];

// 認証用div
var authDiv = document.getElementById('auth-div');
// 実行用div
var execDiv = document.getElementById('exec-div');

// アクセス時に実行
function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

// 初期化処理
function initClient() {
    // GoogleAPIの初期化
    gapi.client.init(
        {
            apiKey: API_KEY
            , discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS
            , clientId: CLIENT_ID
            , scope: SCOPES.join(' ')
        }
    ).then(function () {
        // ログイン状態取得
        let isSignIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();

        if (isSignIn) {
            // ログイン済みなら、実行用の項目表示
            execDisplay();
        } else {
            // 未ログインなら、ログイン用の項目表示
            loginDisplay();
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("エラー: " + error);
    });
}

// ログイン用の項目表示
function loginDisplay() {
    // 未ログイン
    authDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    execDiv.style.display = 'none';
}

// 実行用の項目表示
function execDisplay() {
    // ログイン済み
    authDiv.style.display = 'none';
    execDiv.style.display = 'inline';
}


// 認証ボタンクリック時
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
        .then(function (res) {
            // ログイン認証成功
            execDisplay();
        }, function (error) {
            // ログイン認証失敗
            console.log("ログイン認証失敗: " + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
}

// 実行ボタンクリック時
function execution(event) {

    let request = {
        'function': 'exec'
        , 'parameters': []
    };

    let op = gapi.client.request(
        {
            'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com'
            , 'path': 'v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run'
            , 'method': 'POST'
            , 'body': request
        }
    );

    op.execute(function (res) {
        // console.log("実行結果: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));

        if (res.error) {
            // エラーがある場合
            if (res.error.status) {
                console.log('API実行エラー: ' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
            } else {
                // スクリプトエラーの場合
                let error = res.error.details[0];
                console.log('スクリプトエラー: ' + error.errorMessage);
            }
        } else {
            let json = JSON.parse(res.response.result);
            // console.log(json);

            // 実行結果表示ラベル
            let execLabel = document.getElementById('exec-result');

            if (json.result === 'ok') {
                execLabel.innerText = '' + '\r\n';
                execLabel.innerText += '正常終了しました。';
            } else {
                execLabel.innerText = '処理エラー';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**index.gs**

```
function exec() {
  let res = {
    "test": 123
    }
  let json = res
  return JSON.stringify(json)
}
```

index.html表示すると
未ログインの時は、「認証ボタン」が表示されます。
ログイン済みの時は、「実行ボタン」が表示されます。

「実行ボタン」をクリックすると、問題ない場合は「実行結果: 正常終了しました。」が表示されます。